# При чтении данных с firebase database приходит null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Есть фрагмент с recyclerView + cardView. Данные в карточки считываются с firebase database. Когда в карточке было три элемента - key, title, poem - все прекрасно работало. Но мне нужно добавить поля subject и years. Добавляю точно также как и первые, в firebase ключи совпадают c элементами списка. Когда дебажу модель данных, выдает такое [image: screen]

Здесь меняла Object на String.

```
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("title", title);
    result.put("poem", poem);
    result.put("key", key);
    result.put("subject", subject);
    result.put("years", years);
```

Не помогло.

В коде я закомментила строки, на которые указано в логах. (И без этих двух строк все работает)

```
 public class ModelPoem {
    public String title;
    public String poem;
    public String subject;
    public String years;
    public int key;


    public ModelPoem() {
    }

    public ModelPoem(String title, String poem, int key, String subject, String years) {
        this.title = title;
        this.poem = poem;
        this.key = key;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.years = years;
    }


    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("title", title);
        result.put("poem", poem);
        result.put("key", key);
        result.put("subject", subject);
        result.put("years", years);


        return result;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPoem() {
        return poem;
    }

    public void setPoem(String poem) {
        this.poem = poem.replace("_n", "\r\n");
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getYears() {
        return years;
    }

    public void setYears(String years) {
        this.years = years;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}



public class PoemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PoemAdapter.PoemViewHolder> {

    private List<ModelPoem> list;

    public PoemAdapter(List<ModelPoem> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PoemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new PoemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model_poem, parent, false));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PoemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ModelPoem modelPoem = list.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(modelPoem.title);
        holder.poem.setText(modelPoem.poem);
     //   holder.years.setText(modelPoem.years);
     //   holder.subject.setText(modelPoem.subject);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    class PoemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView poem;
        CardView cv;
        TextView subject;
        TextView years;
        ImageView subject_image;
        ImageView years_image;

        PoemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            poem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_poem);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            subject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
            years = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_years);
            subject_image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_subject);
            years_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_years);

        }
    }
}

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: rodionova.lyubov.brodsky, PID: 18386
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at rodionova.lyubov.brodsky.adapter.PoemAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PoemAdapter.java:41)
                      at rodionova.lyubov.brodsky.adapter.PoemAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PoemAdapter.java:21)
```

model_poem.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="12dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_poem"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="45dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="0dp"/>

            </FrameLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:divider="@drawable/separator"
                android:dividerPadding="3dp"
                android:showDividers="middle">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_subject"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/pound"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_subject"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_years"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar_range"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_years"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Проблема не в базе и не в модели, а в том что в разметке элемента списка (`model_poem.xml`) не найден `TextView` с таким `id`.

Comment: Прикрепила разметку.  Да я подставляла на место рабочего "title" "subject", чтоб проверить работоспособность, остальные стирала. Но именно subject и years не хотят работать.

Comment: Как-будто всё правильно, видимо Instant Run чудит. Попробуйте сделайте `Rebuild Project`, если не поможет, то удалите приложение с девайса, потом ребилд и запуск. P.S.  Я Instant Run не использую, возможно есть более правильный способ его укротить...

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. И даже радикальный Invalidate Cashes / Restart. Значит все-таки ошибка где-то. В любом случае спасибо за отклик.

Comment: А у Вас один файл `model_poem.xml`? Альтернативных нет - типа портрет/ландшафт?

Comment: Слона-то я и не приметила) Спасибо Вам большое!  Был еще макет v-21